# Problema com o tamanho do header

Tags: html, css, header

Estou sofrendo com um código onde eu preciso deixar determinado um banner com um tamanho pré-determinado no navegador ao abrir a página, mas toda vez que eu abro a página, ele fica do tamanho total do navegador.
Nao sei exatamente como determinar este parâmetro em CSS (ou HTML) e a partir de onde devo fazer.

Abaixo, segue um modelo do que eu quero fazer.
1 - Imagem com o banner ajustado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Imagem com a tela cheia (o que nao quero)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe algum tipo de `div` com o tamanho pré-determinado?
Alguém me pode ajudar? Segue o meu código CSS:

```
header {
    position: relative;
}
header .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/slider-overlay.png) repeat;
}
header .carousel,
header .item,
header .active {
    height: 100%; /* Aqui se eu colocar 1024px, o css nao assume o tamanho determinado */
}
.carousel-inner {
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Esse background é para ser no overlay mesmo?

Comment: Por favor, mostre o código html

Comment: mas esse que você mandou já está funcionando OK. Para o seu problema, é preciso o código que você está usando.

Comment: Ola Rafael, é o mesmo código. Se vc abrir o codigo em um navegador, voce verá que o banner abrirá por inteiro, eu gostaria de ter o controle do tamanho do banner para que possa ser visto com os demais conteudos da pagina abaixo. Eu nao gostaria que o banner fosse em tela cheia no navegador.